# UITextField where to set clearsOnBeginEditing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, interface-builder

I'm really used to VS where all properties are nicely listed in a big dialog.

In Interface Builder I can find no such dialog.

If I want to set the clearsOnBeginEditing field of a UITextField to FALSE, where is the best place to do it?  Is there an interface to a control's properties in interface builder that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is available through the inspector in IB:

[IB Inspector view http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/3015/screenshot20091101at155.png](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/3015/screenshot20091101at155.png)